# How to pause all threads while the window is suspended

Tags: multithreading, task, monogame

I noticed that when working with the Monogame framework that threads are not paused when the game stops drawing. Such as moving the window around. This is a minor problem with the game continuing while the player can't see; Its an even bigger problem when using tasks.

So how do I pause all threads when the game window is suspended or not drawing?

Comment: Someone will suggest Thread.Suspend. Don't use it, it can break your game in hard to test ways. It might pause the static ctor of System.String or another important class. Everything locks up then.

Comment: Well is there anything in particular you would suggest?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about Monogame. Just trying to save you this common mistake.

Comment: Ah alright, well hopefully someone can shed some light on the situation or else making this game is gonna be even more tedious.

Comment: If this is a school project you can probably get away with Thread.Suspend and nobody will notice :)

Comment: This is more of a personal project that I'm gonna use for a game and then release the project as open source. I'm trying to make it worth while like a scripting engine I use that is able to multitask but have the code still run together if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Someone will suggest Thread.Suspend. Don't use it, it can break your game in hard to test ways. It might pause the static ctor of System.String or another important class. Everything locks up then. This is hard to test for so you'll likely find out in production at a surprising time.

Pausing threads has to be cooperative. A simple way to do it is to have an event that all threads regularly wait on. When you want to pause you unset the event:

```
static readonly AutoResetEvent evt = new ...;
//...
while (...) { //some game loop
 evt.WaitOne();
 DoWork();
}
```

[This has been made into a nice `PauseToken` class.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods.aspx)

It would be easier to give a good answer if there was some code and more context in the question. But this should get you started on the idea of pausing threads cooperatively.

Comment: Thanks, the pause token class set up seemed to have worked. But when I implemented it into my game the method was getting caused twice, even though there was only one instance of the class it was called in as well as one call to the actual method.

I'm going forget about multi-tasking for now. I only need to be able to create danmaku games and complex patterns without a giant stack of if statements. If you know a good way of doing that, I would like to hear it. Otherwise, thanks for the help.